# send list through ajax but model is empty in controller action

Tags: ajax

I have model of list in which I get list of two parameters. Data send from view is correct but in controller action it is null

```
        var model = {   
                "IdeaFinancials": ideaFinancials
           };
        model = JSON.stringify({ 'model': model });
        $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("TeamMapping", "Team")',
                type: 'Post',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: model,
                success: function (res) {
                $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
                 },
                failure: function (response) {
                $('#result').html(response);

            });
```

In Controller Acton

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult TeamMapping (IEnumerable<UsersTeamMapping> model)
        {
            var mo = _roleServices.GetRolesList();
           return Json(mo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

But model is still empty

Comment: UsersTeamMapping must contain or assign the template then called

Answer (score 0):

```
        var model = {   
                "IdeaFinancials": ideaFinancials
           };
        $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("TeamMapping", "Team")',
                type: 'Post',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                success: function (res) {
                $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
                 },
                failure: function (response) {
                $('#result').html(response);

            });
```

inside the UsersTeamMapping must contain the IdeaFinancials attributes check if it contains

Class C#

```
public class UsersTeamMapping
    {
        public List<string> IdeaFinancials { get; set; }
    }


[HttpPost]
public JsonResult TeamMapping (UsersTeamMapping model)
{
  var mo = _roleServices.GetRolesList();
  return Json(mo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```